# RadioButton adapter not sending String instead of actual RadioButton to the listView

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, android-custom-view, android-adapter

EDIT: With using some of the links from the answers, I just made a custom adapter(literally less than 10 lines of code), and everything works nice now. Here is the `CustomAdapter` I made in case someone ends up with a similar problem. Note, the `CustomAdapter` works with any class that extends 'View'.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
List<View> views;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<View> views){
    this.context = context;
    this.views = views;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return views.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    return views.get(i);
}}
```

I made a simple `Activity` that is suppose to show the list of `radioButtons` that I pass to it. To test things out, before passing it to the `activity`, I just tried to create a new `RadioButton` inside the `activity`, add it to the list, and have an adapter pass it to the `listView`.

```
public class SpecialListActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<RadioButton> adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_special_list);

        List<RadioButton> list = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();

        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButton.setText("test");

        list.add(radioButton);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RadioButton>(this,R.layout.message_row,list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Here is the .xml filem its pretty simple, has only a listView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The result that I expected, is for a single RadioButton to show up on the list, but the results are a bit different.
[image]

What may be the cause of this behavior, and how can I try to make the list show an actual radiobutton, or any other customView?

Comment: what is your R.layout.message_row

Comment: No clue to be honest, it was there, and it all worked when I tried this out with strings, didn't think much of it.

Comment: then use custom adapter that might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have define RadioButton data type in List and ArrayAdapter and you are passing object of RadioButton, so it will print RadioButton object.

If you want to pass text of RadioButton then use below code.

```
public class SpecialListActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_special_list);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
    radioButton.setText("test");

    list.add(radioButton.getText().toString());

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.message_row,list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

If you want to create custom ListView with RadioButton then use below link. 
http://abhiandroid.com/ui/radiobutton-inside-listview.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works. You have to use `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` with a String list to populate single choice `ListView`.Below is an example try it out .

```
 String[] names = new String[] { "Canada", "USA", "Iceland", "Ireland"};
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    listView.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
            android.R.id.text1, names));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are saying. I already made a list that gets Strings and puts them in a `listView`. Are you sure your solution has anything to do with `customViews`, I don't see anything similar in the solution you provided. I tried to run the code, `listView` does not contain the `setListAdapter()` method.

Comment: You put `RadioButton` in list not `String` . And the bit different result you added above is hex equivalent of this `RadioButton's` object .